# Rails ActiveAdmin DSL helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to use helper methods when defining ActiveAdmin pages. In particular:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Catalog do
  menu parent: menu_title(:catalog)
end
```

where

```
def menu_title(s)
  proc { I18n.t("active_admin.menus.#{s}") }
end
```

Where do I put `menu_title`? Putting it in `ViewsHelper` doesn't work, and the documentation seems silent on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is one ugly solution.

In the ActiveAdmin initializer file, add at the bottom (outside the block):

```
require Rails.root.join('lib', 'active_admin_dsl.rb')
```

Create a file `lib/active_admin_dsl.rb` with the following contents:

```
class ActiveAdmin::DSL
  def menu_title(s)
    proc { I18n.t("active_admin.menus.#{s}") }
  end

  # or whatever
end
```

Another less ugly but more cumbersome solution is to write a module and then include it manually in each registered resource:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foo do
  include DSLHelper
end
```

But it's certainly impractical when you have *lots* of resources.